# Finding $\arg\min \sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n}{j} \frac{1}{1-(1-2x)^j}$ for $x \in (0, 1)$.

Tags: calculus, group-theory, optimization, binomial-coefficients

> For a positive integer $n$, let $p_n$ be the value of $x \in (0, 1)$ that minimizes $f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n}{j} \frac{1}{1-(1-2x)^j}$ on the stated interval. What is $p_n$?

The function $1/(1-(1-2x)^j)$ is decreasing at least on the interval $(0, 1/2)$. Hence, $p_n \in [1/2, 1)$ other than $p_1$ since $p_1 = 1$. Also, if $j$ is odd, then it is decreasing on $(0, 1)$, but if $j$ is even, then it is increasing on $(1/2, 1)$.

I would be very interested in at least answering the three questions below.

---

#### Background to the question

Let $G$ be the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$, and let $g \in G$. Then a simple consequence of Theorem 3.3 of [this paper on evolutionary algorithms](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.08021), is that $f(x)$ equals the hitting time of $g$ for the random walk below that starts from a uniform distribution on $G$.

The random walk $X_0, X_1,\ldots$ is defined as follows: Let $X_0$ be uniformly distributed on $G$. Given $X_i \in G$, flip each bit independently with probability $x$. Equivalently, go from $X_i$ to $X_i+w$ with probability $\mu(w)$, where $\mu$ is a probability on $G$ defined by $\mu(w) = x^{|w|}(1 - x)^{\ell -|w|}$, where $|w|$ is the number of 1's in $w$ when viewed as an element of $\{0, 1\}^n$.

The hitting time of $g$ is defined as $\min \{ t | X_t = g \}$.

---

#### Three questions

Both my intuition on this problem as well as the results I found doing some programming suggest that the answers to the following questions are all "yes."

> Is $p_n > 1/2$ for all $n$?

> Is $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n = 1/2?$

> Does $p_n$ decrease monotonically?

But I haven't proven that the answers to these questions are what I think they are.

Comment: This is interesting. However, you would get a better response if you asked those three questions separately.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to each of the last three questions is "yes."

First, Claude Leibovici's answer inspired this observation that proves $p_n > 1/2$ for all $n$. For the other two questions, see [this other question I asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4642430/showing-the-root-of-sum-j-1n-binomnj-fracj-xj-11-xj2-appr).

---

Proof that $p_n > 1/2$:

Notice that
$$f'(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n}{j} \frac{-2j(1-2x)^{j-1}}{(1-(1-2x)^j)^2},$$
and so $f'(1/2) = -2n$ (since the expression $(1-2x)^{j-1}$ should be interpreted as $1$ if $j=1$).

Therefore, since we already know from $f$ itself that $f(x)$ is decreasing on the interval $(0, 1/2)$, and since $f'(1/2) < 0$, that implies that $p_n > 1/2$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

In my former research group, we worked the problem of the zero of almost $f'(x)$. So, using our results, let $x=\frac {1-\epsilon}2$ and look for the zero of
$$g_n(\epsilon)=\sum_{j=1}^n j \binom{n}{j}\frac{ \epsilon ^{j-1}}{\left(1-\epsilon^j\right)^2}$$
which, at least for me, is better conditioned and clearly shows what happens if $\epsilon \to 0^{\pm}$.

Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  n   &   \epsilon_n \\
 10   &  -0.134716881 \\
 20   &  -0.086462117 \\
 30   &  -0.066032636 \\
 40   &  -0.054260339 \\
 50   &  -0.046456858 \\
 60   &  -0.040843618 \\
 70   &  -0.036581901 \\
 80   &  -0.033219461 \\
 90   &  -0.030488889 \\
 100  &  -0.028221051 \\
 200  &  -0.016758959 \\
 300  &  -0.012240459 \\
 400  &  -0.009757941 \\
 500  &  -0.008168496 \\
 600  &  -0.007055481 \\
 700  &  -0.006228588 \\
 800  &  -0.005587850 \\
  900 &  -0.005075452 \\
 1000 &  -0.004655514 \\
 2000 &  -0.002618885 \\
 3000 &  -0.001860867 \\
 4000 &  -0.001457237 \\
 5000 &  -0.001204184 \\
 6000 &  -0.001029721 \\
 7000 &  -0.000901681 \\
 8000 &  -0.000803449 \\
 9000 &  -0.000725546 \\
 10000 &  -0.000662189 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

These points align along an hyperbole with an asymptotic value of $0^-$. So, $p_n \to \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^+$.

If $\epsilon$ is small, the summand can be expanded as a series
$$\frac{ \epsilon ^{j-1}}{\left(1-\epsilon^j\right)^2}=\frac 1 \epsilon \frac{ \epsilon ^{j}}{\left(1-\epsilon^j\right)^2}=\frac 1 \epsilon \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \, \epsilon^{kj}$$

Summing, expanding again

$$\frac {g_n(\epsilon)}n=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {P_k(n)}{k!}\,\epsilon^k $$ where the first polynomials in $n$ are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & n+1 \\
 2 & n^2-3 n+8 \\
 3 & n^3-6 n^2+23 n+6 \\
 4 & n^4-10 n^3+35 n^2-50 n+144 \\
 5 & n^5-15 n^4+85 n^3-105 n^2+274 n+480 \\
 6 & n^6-21 n^5+175 n^4-735 n^3+1624 n^2-1764 n+5760 \\
 7 & n^7-28 n^6+322 n^5-1960 n^4+8449 n^3-23212 n^2+51708 n+5040   \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using series reversion does not give good approximation but reproduces the trends. Truncating to $k=10$, with $m=n+1$, leads to
$$\epsilon=-\frac{7381}{2520 m}+\frac{2121533}{50400 m^2}-\frac{598739003}{907200
   m^3}+\frac{113076059}{13440 m^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^5}\right)$$ but the coefficient depend on the value of $k_{\text{max}}$.

Much better is to perform a series expansion around $\epsilon=-\frac 1{n+1}$ to $O\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^6\right)$ and use a series reversion.

For the first values of $n$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 10 & -0.134717\\
 20 & -0.086459\\
 30 & -0.066025\\
 40 & -0.054246\\
 50 & -0.046437\\
 60 & -0.040818\\
 70 & -0.036552\\
 80 & -0.033186\\
  90 & -0.030454\\
 100 & -0.028186\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

The idea of series reversion was $\color{red}{\text{bad}}$.

Using
$$\frac{ \epsilon ^{j-1}}{\left(1-\epsilon^j\right)^2}=\epsilon ^{j-1}+2 \epsilon ^{2 j-1}+O\left(\epsilon ^{3 j-1}\right)$$ we look for the inverse of the equation
$$n=\frac{\log \left(-\frac{2 \epsilon  (\epsilon +1)}{\epsilon
   ^2+1}\right)}{\log \left(\frac{\epsilon +1}{\epsilon
   ^2+1}\right)}$$ Expanding the rhs again, it gives
$$n-1=\frac{\log (-2 \epsilon )}{\epsilon }+\frac{3}{2} \log (-2
   \epsilon )+\frac{23}{12} \epsilon  \log (-2 \epsilon
   )+O\left(\epsilon ^2 \log (-2 \epsilon )\right)$$

$$n-1\sim\frac{\log (-2 \epsilon )}{\epsilon }\quad \implies \quad \color{red}{ \epsilon\sim-\frac{W\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}{n-1}}$$ which, for $n=10,20,\cdots$, gives
$$\{-0.140804,-0.0901594,-0.0685292,-0.0560925,-0.047877\}$$

Comment: Note that in the last expansion, it seems that each term is of order $n^{-1}$ for large $n$.

Comment: @Gary. Yes for sure.